# How can I get a value of an entity in TypeDB using Nodejs client?

Tags: node.js, vaticle-typedb

I try to get the actual values of entity attributes within a nodejs client but I only get the string Ids. I tried many different versions of .getValue() or asAttribute or getAttribute but just get error messages. How can I retrieve the actual values of attributes?

This is my code

````
export async function getMarketByTitle(title: string) {
  const database = "know_graph"; // Replace this with the name of your TypeDB database
  const { client, session, transaction } = await openTransaction(database);

  try {
    const query = `
      match
      $m isa market, has title "${title}", has background_information $background_information;
      $m has title $m_title;
      get $m, $m_title, $background_information;
    `;

    const iterator = await transaction.query.match(query);
    let market;
    for await (const answer of iterator) {
      const mConcept = answer.get("m");
      const mTitle = answer.get("m_title");
      const backgroundInformation = answer.get("background_information");
      const checkEntity = mConcept.isEntity();
      const checkAttribute = mTitle.isAttribute();

      market = {
        id: mConcept.toString(),
        title: msTitle.toString(),
        backgroundInformation: backgroundInformation.toString(),
        entity: checkEntity.toString(),
        attribute: checkAttribute.toString
      };

      return market;
    }```
````

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should use `.map` and `.value`, like that:

```
      const mTitle = answer.map.get("m_title").value;
      const backgroundInformation = answer.map.get("background_information").value;
```

As per https://typedb.com/docs/clients/2.x/node-js/node-js-api-ref.html#_retrieve_value_local (updated the link for the new docs URL!).

Can't comment on James's answer, so I'll add the link to the JSON method here: https://typedb.com/docs/clients/2.x/node-js/node-js-api-ref.html#_retrieve_a_concept_as_json

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Concept API as Vladimir pointed out. We have also just released JSON output in all of our clients so you should be able to call `.toJSONRecord()` on your concept maps and the output will contain all the information contained in the concept map.

Edit: Make sure you're using client version 2.17 or later.